# Does Redis hash store field & value as string?

Tags: database, redis

It is mentioned [here](https://redis.com/glossary/redis-hashes/#:%7E:text=Redis%20hashes%20store%20field%20values,in%20a%20relational%20database%20table.), fields of hash are stored as strings

We have a redis hash model for a record:

```
hash 5ADDD::222345 {
   mobileNum: 535345345
   model: A3FSSS
   timestamp: 543543544
   error:
```

}

redis key in this case, is a composite key(of three values, where second or third can be NULL)

here `error` has no value

---

1. Is the redis key stored as string?
2. Are the field values stored as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. The field, value, and the key itself are all stored as Redis Strings.

Comment: One supplementary, query,  does redis internally [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) state in cache to files? for persistency...